# Counting Date Columns in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting stuck on how to count a date. I have 3 different columns: 
demodate1, demodate2, demodate3

If demodate1 exists I want to count it as 1, if demodate 2 exists, I want to count it as 1, if demodate3 exists I want to count it as 1. If more than 1 of those exist I want to add them all together.

How can I do this?

Here's my try at the code:

```
      def demosheld
        if demodate1.present? or demodate2.present? or demodate3.present?
          demodate1.count + demodate2.count + demodate3.count
        end   
      end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def demosheld
  count = 0
  count = count + (demodate1.present? ? 1 : 0)
  count = count + (demodate2.present? ? 1 : 0)
  count = count + (demodate3.present? ? 1 : 0)
end
```

**Edit:**

Other options are

```
[demodate1, demodate2, demodate3].inject{|sum,date| sum + date.present? ? 1 : 0 }
```

---

```
sum = 0
[demodate1, demodate2, demodate3].each { |date| sum += date.present? ? 1 : 0 }
```

Comment: I thought I'd be able to also check if the date is after a certain date. Combining your method with another     count = count + (demodate1.present? && demodate1 >= Date.new(2012, 2, 23) ? 1 : 0) but it doesn't work. Where am I missing it?

Comment: It ended up working. There was an error in the database I needed to correct. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

How about some inject magic?

```
def demosheld
  [demodate1, demodate2, demodate3].inject(0) do |sum, date|
    sum + (date.present? ? 1 : 0)
  end
end
```